# Почему фон у картинки обрезается только с одной стороны?

Tags: php, gd

Есть такой код:

```
$imagejpeg = imagecreatefromjpeg("test.jpg");
$imagejpeg = imagecropauto($imagejpeg, IMG_CROP_WHITE);

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
echo imagejpeg($imagejpeg);
```

Прикладываю картинку test.jpg. И результат скрипта. Почему-то у нее обрезается фон только с правой стороны. Я пробовал немного убрать у нее границы через imagecrop (на 10px ширину и высоту) и применить функцию imagecropauto - не помогло. Я пробовал после применения imagecropauto повернуть картинку через imagerotate и снова применить imagecropauto - не помогло.
Почему не работает? Как обрезать фон у картинки?

Открывайте картинки в новой вкладке (в хроме при просмотре jpg черный фон), т.к. на stackoverflow белый фон и у картинки белый фон. Не видно, что обрезалось, а что - нет.

До применения скрипта:

[image: До применения скрипта]

После применения скрипта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

потому что это тебе не png... пробуй

```
$croppedImg = imagecropauto($img, IMG_CROP_THRESHOLD, /* в диапазоне от 0.1 до 0.5 */, 16777215);
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. А почему мой код не работает? Почему надо использовать именно IMG_CROP_THRESHOLD?

Comment: потому что jpeg использует сжатие/оптимизацию и зачастую при сохранении цвета искажаются. если не понятно, то сохрани этот файл с минимальным качеством. IMG_CROP_THRESHOLD использует диапазон цветов и поэтому оптимален для jpg.